# Community♦ profile doesn't onebox in chat

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, community-user, onebox

When I post a link to the [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) profile in chat, it doesn't onebox.

I'd wager that this has something to do with the negative user ID, but the Stack Exchange API seems to handle it just fine when I try it [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids).

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say the answer is something like, "Blame balpha," but I'm not a betting gal.

Comment: It is a good observation, but I'm not sure this is a key case for fixing - it isn't *really* a user, after all

Comment: @MarcGravell Nonsense, this is srs bsns! It should onebox an image of Community in an epic battle with Feeds instead.

Comment: There, there, Community, @Marc didn't _really_ mean that. He's just had a rough day. Come on, let's go visit balpha, I'm sure he'll have some abandoned accounts for you to take over!

Comment: __"@TimStone I got winner! -Crickets"__